# Does APNs Authentication Key ever expire?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've setup Firebase Cloud Messaging on our system to setup push notifications. Before our APNs certificate expired and we ran into some issues because of this.

Then I was able to generate an APNs Authentication Key and I assumed that this one couldn't expire. Can someone tell me if that assumption is correct?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

No. APNs Auth Key will never expire as Apple suggests. It is now a more preferred way to handle Push Notifications than using APNs Certificate.

Comment: But it is still might be revoked.

Comment: for newbies (me), the following url has easy-to-understand directions for creating APN Auth Key https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/marketing/responsys-develop-mobile/ios/auth-key.htm#:~:text=To%20create%20an%20APNs%20auth,to%20create%20a%20new%20key.